# Count and print columns from two different tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `'user' and 'user_project'`.

user table:

```
| username | user_type | 
+----------+-----------+
| adam     | CT        |
| bob      | AP        |
| cat      | AP        |
```

`user_project`:

```
| projectNo | process | username | 
+-----------+---------+----------+
| 16090001  | ANM     | adam     |
| 16090001  | ANM     | bob      |
| 16090001  | BLD     | adam     |
```

I want to calculate appeareance of same name, display that username, number of appeareances AND `user_type`.

But I am able to print only username and `COUNT`. What I have so far:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(username) names FROM 
    (SELECT username FROM `user_project` WHERE projectNo=16120001
                        UNION ALL
    SELECT username FROM `user` ) t GROUP BY username
```

Here is my expected output:

```
| username | user_type | count | 
+----------+-----------+-------+
| adam     | CT        | 3     |
| bob      | AP        | 2     |
| cat      | AP        | 1     |
```

How can I print all three columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a subquery on the `user_project` table to aggregate appearances by user, and then join this back to the `user` table.

```
SELECT t1.username,
       t1.user_type,
       COALESCE(t2.num_appearences, 0) AS `count`
FROM user t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS num_appearences
    FROM user_project
    WHERE projectNo = <some_number>
    GROUP BY username
) t2
    ON t1.username = t2.username
```

Comment: Got an error: `Unknown column 't2.num_appearences' in 'field list'`

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy Typo, please try again.

Comment: I need to use `WHERE projectNo='$projectNo'` as I need get information about one project.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can select DISTINCT column name FROM table_name

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT username) FROM user_project;

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include descriptions of how this code works, so that it may be beneficial to future users.

Comment: sure i will provide description